# Outlook 2016 - Modify Appointment Window

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office365, outlook-2016

Wondering if there is a way to modify the Appointment window in outlook 2016 to add new fields?

1. A resource field that would be a drop down menu containing
       different alphanumeric text field selections.
2. A Numeric data type entry field.
3. A Text data type entry field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a custom form based on the IPM.Appointment class or create a form region associated with that class.  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/customizing-form-pages-and-form-regions.

You can also host your UI in a custom Windows Form on a custom Task Pane adjoining the Appointment window by using a .NET add-in.